# How to work in one partial view while another one is getting load in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view where I am using 4 partial view.
when page gets load. All 4 partial views are getting loaded. So to start working
I have to wait to upload all partial view.

I have to do that I should work on 
first partial view while second one is getting load and so on for all next partial views. So plz suggest me the solution.

my partial views like that

```
    <div>@Html.Partial("_First")</div>
    <div>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller1/_Second.cshtml")</div>
    <div>@Html.Partial("_Third")</div>
    <div>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller2/_Forth.cshtml")</div>
```

Comment: `Html.Partial` is including the partial view *in the server-side*, it does not cause an Ajax request to load the partial in the client-side. So when your page is loaded, all the partials are already there.

Comment: Yes, and if you want to do so, use Ajax to load partial views. So that partial views will start loading after main view loads. You can show loading images inside all your DIVs where you are showing partial views.

Answer (score 0):

Give your divs id's and use Ajax to load the partial views after the page has loaded.

```
 <div id="firstId">@Html.Partial("_First")</div>
 <div id="secondId">@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller1/_Second.cshtml")</div>
 <div id="thirdId">@Html.Partial("_Third")</div>
 <div id="fourthId">@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller2/_Forth.cshtml")</div>
```

Do somehting like this for your Ajax call...

```
 <script>
      $(function loadPartialView1()  {
           $.ajax({
                url: '@url.Action("_First", "YourControllerNameHere")',
                type:  'Post',
                data: {''},
                cache:  'false'
                async:  'true',
                success:   function (result)  {
                     $('#firstId').html(result);
                }
           });
      });
      ...for each one of your PartialViews
 </script
```

The syntax may be a bit off with the $(function loadPartialView1() part, but that is the shorthand way to make the function wait until the document has loaded.  The long version does not work for me on my MVC 4 project.